# Qt OpenGL - Texture Transparency issue

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transparency

I'm currently trying to learn OpenGL, and I'm having trouble with texture transparency.

I have 2 planes/rectangles that are textured, the first is closest to the camera, the second is further back, behind the first one. Both are textured with an image that has a background at 50% opacity.

I should be able to see the texture of the second plane behind the first since the first is transparent to some degree - but I don't. The images I'm using do in fact appear on their own (can see them if I rotate the camera), and they have words on them (which I would expect to kind of bleed through the semi-transparent background of the image in front).

Is there a way to correct this?
Here is my initialization and paintGL methods (they are probably horribly optimized)

```
void oglWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::white));

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vertexShader.vsh");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragmentShader.fsh");
    shaderProgram.link();

    //    vertices[1] << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  0) << QVector3D( xAmt, -1,  0) << QVector3D( xAmt,  1,  0) // Front
    //            << QVector3D( xAmt, 1,  0) << QVector3D(-xAmt,  1,  0) << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  0);

    float xAmt = 16.00/9.00;
    vertices << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  0) << QVector3D( xAmt, -1,  0) << QVector3D( xAmt,  1,  0) // Midground
             /*<< QVector3D( xAmt, 1,  0) << QVector3D(-xAmt,  1,  0) << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  0)*/
             << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  -1) << QVector3D( xAmt, -1,  -1) << QVector3D( xAmt,  1,  -1) // Background
             << QVector3D( xAmt, 1,  -1) << QVector3D(-xAmt,  1,  -1) << QVector3D(-xAmt, -1,  -1);


    textureCoordinates << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Front
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0)
                       << QVector2D(0, 0) << QVector2D(1, 0) << QVector2D(1, 1) // Front
                       << QVector2D(1, 1) << QVector2D(0, 1) << QVector2D(0, 0);
}

void oglWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
    QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;

    QMatrix4x4 cameraTransformation;
    cameraTransformation.rotate(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
    cameraTransformation.rotate(beta, 1, 0, 0);

    QVector3D cameraPosition = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 0, distance);
    QVector3D cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * QVector3D(0, 1, 0);

    vMatrix.lookAt(cameraPosition, QVector3D(0, 0, 0), cameraUpDirection);
    shaderProgram.bind();
    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);


    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("texture", 0);
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
    glGenTextures(0, &texture);    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    QImage tempTexture = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(QImage(ImgManager::getImg("/Textures/Editor/m.png")));
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tempTexture.width(), tempTexture.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempTexture.bits() );
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());

    shaderProgram.release();
}
```

Comment: Try disabling the depth test or setting a depth mask.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. If you want to, reply with that as an answer instead of a comment and Ill check it off and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though blending is enabled new geometry will perform a depth test to check if the current fragment is visible **and** populate the depth buffer with new values.

A simple way to fix it is to disable depth testing completly with `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, but the better way is the following:

1. set `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);`
2. Draw Opaque objekts
3. set `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);`
4. Draw transparent objekts

`glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` will disable the writing to the depth buffer while the depth test itself is still enabled. As a result opaque objects will occlude transparent objects only if they are really in front of them.